# Apt update trouble with linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic

Tags: apt, updates

```
: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-24
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-24 linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 4 to remove and 205 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 357 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 234231 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (4.4.0-24.43) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-24-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_Ur3KGV/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_Ur3KGV/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (4.4.0-24.43) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_sxty5m/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_sxty5m/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of the command `apt-cache search Linux-header`

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-21 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-21-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-generic - Generic Linux kernel headers
linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic - Generic Linux kernel headers (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid - Generic Linux kernel headers (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-generic-lts-wily - Generic Linux kernel headers (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial - Generic Linux kernel headers (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-lowlatency - lowlatency Linux kernel headers
linux-headers-lowlatency-lts-utopic - lowlatency Linux kernel headers (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-lowlatency-lts-vivid - lowlatency Linux kernel headers (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-lowlatency-lts-wily - lowlatency Linux kernel headers (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-lowlatency-lts-xenial - lowlatency Linux kernel headers (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-virtual - Transitional package.
linux-headers-virtual-lts-utopic - Transitional package. (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-virtual-lts-vivid - Transitional package. (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-virtual-lts-wily - Transitional package. (dummy transitional package)
linux-headers-virtual-lts-xenial - Transitional package. (dummy transitional package)
linux-libc-dev - Linux Kernel Headers for development
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-source-4.4.0 - Linux kernel source for version 4.4.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-virtual - Minimal Generic Linux kernel and headers
linux-libc-dev-alpha-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-hppa-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-m68k-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpcspe-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-s390x-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sh4-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sparc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-headers-3.4.0-4-goldfish - Linux kernel headers for version 3.4.0 on Android touch emulation
linux-headers-goldfish - Linux kernel headers for the goldfish kernel.
linux-headers-4.4.0-22 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-22-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-24 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-24-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-28 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-28-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-31 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-31-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-34 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-34-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-36 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-36-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-38 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-4.4.0-38-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

The output of the command  `sudo apt install Linux-Headers-4.4.0-22-generic`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic' for glob 'Linux-Headers-4.4.0-22-generic'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-22
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-22 linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 4 to remove and 205 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 10.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 357 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-22 all 4.4.0-22.40 [9,934 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic amd64 4.4.0-22.40 [783 kB]
Fetched 10.7 MB in 9s (1,132 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 234231 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (4.4.0-24.43) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-24-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-24-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_lDYjIO/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_lDYjIO/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (4.4.0-24.43) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_Wz8kA4/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_Wz8kA4/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012': not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
apt-cache search Linux-header
```

It will list all of package name as well as its version to install. I have checked and it installed successfully with:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic
```

Comment: Thx, I got a different response this time apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root? what does this mean? @Ender Phan

Comment: This means that there is either an update process  running which is locking and therefor blocking your attempt or that you don't have the privileges to do so (did you use sudo?)

Comment: Did you use sudo (root permission) to install or current user?

Comment: As `sudo` was missing in your instructions - i assume he was missing that part. I edited your answer @EnderPhan

Comment: Thx, I gave it another try and saw some very familier errors particularly depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_lDYjIO/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory  what do these mean? @dufte

Comment: @Apollo: please add your complete command and output to your initial question above ...should be more readable for all of us ;)

Comment: Sure thing, here ya go :) @dufte